# adding trailing comma to the lines of dynamically created arrays

Tags: php, arrays

I want to add trailing comma to each line of my dynamically created array.

This is how the array need to look. Each line need to seperated by a trailing comma.

```
[
'message'      => 'A new comment',
'messagetwo'   => 'A new comment',
'messagethree' => 'A new comment'
];
```

This is how I tried to dynamically create it:

```
   $array= [];

    foreach($data as $key => $value){
        $array += [$key => "$value". ','];
    }
```

**The error result:**

```
array:5 [
  "message" => "A new comment,"
  "messagetwo" => "A new comment,"
  "messagethree" => "A new comment,"
]
```

the trailing comma needs to be after the inverted quotes

**UPDATE:**

The reason why I need this is that i am trying to place the array within a function (Laravel create method)

i.e THIS is how it should look within the function.

```
$comment = $post->comments()->create(
  [
   'message'      => 'A new comment',
   'messagetwo'   => 'A new comment',
  'messagethree' => 'A new comment',
  ]
);
```

This is how i intend to add it to the array to the function:

```
$comment = $post->comments()->create([
    $array
]);
```

this is the original array (it's a post array):

```
array:5 [
 
  "title" => "A new comment"
  "messagetwo" => "A new comment"
  "messagethree" => "A new comment"
]
```

Comment: What does `$data` look like? About "This is how the array need to look", isn't that just an array? How or where should it look like that? If you are dynamically adding key => value pairs to an array, then that is what it is supposed to look like.

Comment: Do you know what are arrays in the first place? Why do you think a comma is necessary for dynamically created arrays? PHP already knows what it is!

Comment: Hi @Thefourthbird i have edited my original question to answer your questions

Comment: @paulkendal23 I think you can just use `->create($originalPostArray)` as your original (post) array already is an array. **Note** that if you are using `[$array]` you are wrapping an array in an array, I don't think you want that extra wrapping looking at your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Update

As I first thought before editing your question you wanted to reformat the array, but you don't need to do so. Just give the array.

```
$comment = $post->comments()->create($array);
```

With the following you are creating an array with an array as first element!

```
$comment = $post->comments()->create([$array]);
```

---

If you want your own representation of an array, you should create string.

Here for example is a simple custom dumper (only caring about string as values).

You may remove the "\t" (tab), added for nicer display.

```
$source = [
    'message'      => 'A new comment',
    'messagetwo'   => 'A new comment',
    'messagethree' => 'A new comment'
];

customDumpArray($source);

function customDumpArray(array $array)
{
    $keyLength = max(array_map('strlen', array_values($array))) + 1;
    $size = count($array);
    $i = 0;
    echo "[\n";
    foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
        printf("\t%-{$keyLength}s => '%s'%s\n", "'$key'", $value, ++$i !== $size ? ',' : '');
    }
    echo "]\n";
}
```

Which will output

```
[
    'message'      => 'A new comment',
    'messagetwo'   => 'A new comment',
    'messagethree' => 'A new comment'
]
```